# android studio app does not run on emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

This is my first time using android studio and I would appreciate your help here . I try to run my app on an emulator and while the emulator runs smoothly the app does not appear on it and when I run the app it just says `Gradle build finished` and stops . I'm pretty sure the problem is in the app configuration but I have no prior experience.

My androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mobileapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If more info is needed for this ask me and I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build is not to install the program on Android Studio

First make sure your emulator is available in Android Studio.

I have provided a picture as a reminder.

[image: reminder]

Answer (score 1):

You can try running on real android devices. Go to developer settings. Open debugging and connect your device to computer. When you click start on android studio it will open.